# string can't convert lowercase to upper case as c program

Tags: c, string, uppercase

How can I convert a string using the `toupper` function? This did not work.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main(){
    char ch[20];
    printf("\nEnter Your String :");
    gets(ch);

    int i=0;
    for(i=0;ch[i] !='\0';i++)
    {
        putchar(toupper(ch[i]));
        putchar(ch[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

this program output both upper and lowercase i just want to uppercase output.i cant catch my logic fault.please  help me to get clear logic concept

Comment: How does it not work? What output do you expect, and what do you get?

Comment: What doesn't work? What input and output do you get?

Comment: Your program [works as coded :)](http://ideone.com/OB1wi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think This will work

```
for(i=0;ch[i] !='\0';i++)
{
    ch[i]=toupper(ch[i]);
}

//print the string with uppercase
```